# Integrating over Implicit Regions with unspecified parameter

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

So have this code (giving the moment of inertia of a cube)

```
Integrate[x^2 + y^2, 
          {x, y, z} ∈ ImplicitRegion[Max[Abs[x], Abs[y], Abs[z]] < 1, {x, y, z}]]
```

which works fine giving `16/3`. But when I replace `1` by an abstract parameter `a` like in

```
Integrate[x^2 + y^2, 
          {x, y, z} ∈ ImplicitRegion[Max[Abs[x], Abs[y], Abs[z]] < a, {x, y, z}]]
```

I only get something obvious like the following:
[image: Mathematica output]

How can I make *Mathematica* use the formal parameter?

Comment: If you would not need implicit regions you could do this:

        `Integrate[
     x^2 + y^2, {x, y, z} \[Element] Cuboid[a {-1, -1, -1}, a {1, 1, 1}]]`
which leads to:
    `ConditionalExpression[(16 a^5)/3, a > 0]`

but that will probably not solve your problem

Comment: I'm aware of Mathematica's predefined Regions, but I do need `ImplicitRegion` for my actual problem

Comment: That's what I thought (since this problem is of course solvable without the regions). I thought putting the assumption in that a is larger than 0 would help solve it, but that also did not seem to work.

Comment: Adding that assumption also was my first try

Answer (score 1):

maybe rewritting your implicit region as:

```
Integrate[x^2 + y^2, {x, y, z} \[Element] 
  ImplicitRegion[-a <= x <= a && -a <= y <= a && -a <= z <= a, {x, y, 
    z}], Assumptions -> a > 0]

(* (16 a^5)/3 *)
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems that Region doesn't like `Abs`

Comment: Well, Region does like Abs :-) It needs a clear definition of the region:  region = ImplicitRegion[Max[Abs[{x, y, z}]] < a, {{x, -a, a}, {y, -a, a}, {z, -a, a}}], then:  Integrate[x^2 + y^2, Element[{x, y, z}, region], Assumptions -> a > 0] which gives ((16 a^5)/3).

Answer (score 0):

MMA tries to figure out the implicit region without no assumptions about $\{x,y,z\}$ or $a$, so we can tell it what to do in specific cases:

```
 Integrate[x^2 + y^2, {x, y, z} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[
 Evaluate@Reduce[Max[Abs[x], Abs[y], Abs[z]] < a, {x, y, z}, Reals], {x, y, z}]]
```

$\begin{array}{cc}
 \bigg\{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{16 a^5}{3} & a>0 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$